# Solving two questions on combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have recently learned permutations and combinations. While I was practising, I couldn't solve these two questions:

> In how many ways can a group of 14 people eating at a restaurant be divided between 3 tables seating 6, 5 and 3?

This is what I did. So I did:

```
  14C6 + (14 - 6)C5 + 3C3
= 14C6 + 8C5 + 3C3
= 5369
```

But the answer was actually, 168168.

Also,

> A group of 12 guests at a wedding are to travel as passengers from the church to the reception. There are 3 cars: black, silver and blue. Each car holds 4 passengers. Find the number of ways in which the group may travel if Alice and Jack refuse to travel in the same car?

So I calculated how many ways passengers could be arranged with Alice and Jack possibly meeting.

```
  12C4 + (12 - 4)C4 + 4C4
= 12C4 + 8C4 + 4C4
= 566
```

Then I wasn't sure what to do after.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to continue on from the second question?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first one you should take the product and not the sum of those binomial coefficients (see the [Rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product))
$$\binom{14}{6}\binom{14-6}{5}\binom{14-6-5}{3}=\binom{14}{6}\binom{8}{5}\binom{3}{3}=168168.$$
As regards the second one this is my hint. We have $\binom{12-2}{3}$ ways to fill Alice's car, $\binom{12-2-3}{3}$ ways to fill Jack's car. The remaining $4$ guests go in the other car. Now assign the $3$ colors to the $3$ cars:  Alice's car can have $3$ colors, Jack's car $3-1$ colors... 
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by product?

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please explain why I should multiply rather than adding? Thanks

Comment: Not yet... I'm still trying

Comment: @ianc1339 See the link about the rule of product. Have you the book's answer for the second exercise?

Comment: So basically, there are 120 ways to fill Alice's car and 35 ways to fill Jack's car. This means that there will only be one possibility left for the other four. So if I multiply 120 with 35 and 1, I get the answer which is 4200. Is this correct?

Comment: @ianc1339, we apply rule of product in cases where the final answer is derived when all the things (or cases) together lead to it. rule of addition is applied if the events you add are independently leading to answer. For example : In this problem, all combinations are considered only when we do it all all 3 objects, thus rule of product is applied.

Comment: In the beginning, Alice has 3 possibilities(Black, silver and blue). Then, Jack will have 2 possibilities and the final person will have one possibility. So to get the answer, I can basically, do 3! x 4200 = **25200**

Comment: @ianc1339 Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem, the solution is as follows :

Assume Alice and Jack travel in car's as follows :

Assume Alice goes to car 1 and Jack goes to car 2. The number of ways to arrange the other people :

$\binom{10}{3} * \binom{10-3}{3} * \binom{10-3-3}{4} = 4200$.

Actually the number if ways is same for rest of the cases i.e. $(A2, J1), (A2, J3), (A3, J2), (A1, J3), (A3, J1)$. where $A_i = $ Alice goes to car $i$ and $J_i = $ Jack goes to car $i$.

Since, these events independently lead to final answer, we apply rule of addition and the final answer is

$4200 + 4200 + 4200 + 4200 + 4200 + 4200 = 25200$.